# How to key poorly defined entities?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I am in the process of building an application where the requirements are fuzzy.  Originally, I had a table that keyed off a string.

**Table**
SpecialCode varchar(10)
Description varchar(50) (PK)
somevalue int

Originally, SpecialCode could be `null`.  But, it would help to have SpecialCode as part of the primary key with Description.  Now, Description is no longer unique.  So, I went ahead and made SpecialCode part of the key and gave it some bogus default value.

Of course, the bogus value will now have to be accounted for further up the processing pipeline.

In looking back, I think this all would have worked out better if I had inserted an arbitrary seeded identity.  But, I chose not to do this because I have heard so many others say that meaningless keys are a bad practice.

But, I could have shielded myself from changing requirements with this meaningless key.  Are meaningless seeded identities good practice for this scenerio?  Is there a better design to account for these problems that I should have done instead?

Comment: Meaningless seeded identities are only bad when another natural identity exists, which does not seem to be your case.

Comment: Also it would be less than optimal to make foreign key relations to that table if Description was part of the key, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People argue just as strongly that surrogate ids are often the best design. I find that natural keys are often not really unique even when you think they will be and if they are,  they change so frequently they cause a lot of extra db work to keep them updated in the child tables.  Plus joins are faster with integers (although some natural keys can allow you to avoid some joins). This may be highly dependant on the type of data you commonly see, but I strongly prefer surrogate keys with unique indexes on the natural key if one exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can still add an Identity Seed key to this table. It won't hurt any existing code and will allow you to modernize the code.

I always use stored procedures. When I wind up extending table designs I make numbered copies of all my stored procs. For example:

```
spAddDescription   (original)
spAddDescription01 (revision 1)
spAddDescription02 (revision 2)

spUpdateDescription   (original)
spUpdateDescription01 (revision 1)
spUpdateDescription02 (revision 2)
```

This lets me keep things working in production but still allows for slowly integrating the modifications. Typically the higher the revision number means the most recent changes have been incorporated.